# inclusion of static variables as covariates

Tags: r, causalimpact

Is there a clear way to include static variables e.g. elevation as covariates in the CausalImpact pacakge. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Anand

Comment: Although the post (in its original form) appears to focus on software, there may be a statistical question here--but if so, could you formulate it explicitly for us?  What would "include static variables as covariates" amount to in terms of a statistical model or procedure?

Comment: @whuber ; I'm referring to time series analysis [similar to ARIMA models]  specific to the CausalImpact package implemented in r. In the model formulation, you have time-varying covariates; i'm interested in fixed variables that do not change over time. Are you familiar with the package?

Comment: What is your question?  Is it about the software or about the model?

Comment: The software - how to include static variables in the r package "CausalImpact"?